# Directx 12 says that it cannot find the path specified when I run a demo project from a book

Tags: c++, directx

I am trying to learn directx 12 by reading Frank Luna's Introduction to Directx 12 book. I have all of the requirements(at least I think I do anyway), but I still get an error when I try to run the demo project(It came with a source code cd but I don't have a cd drive in my computer, so i had to find the GitHub version instead; but i don't know if it is right or not). When I did this it says
hr failed in \mac\home\esktop\d3d12book-master\common\d3dutil.cpp;line 111;error:The system cannot find the path specified(It says "mac" because i am using a virtual machine).

Here are the book's requirements
Windows 10(which i am running in the virtual machine)
Visual Studio 2015 or Later
A driver that supports directx12

Here is a link to the source code that i downloaded and a link to a pdf file for this book.

GitHub source File:https://github.com/d3dcoder/d3d12book

**Also**
I am using visual studio 2015 community it that really makes a difference

Comment: Looking at line 111 from d3dUtil.cpp, the error comes from a failed call to D3DCompileFromFile, which means it couldn't find a .hlsl file where the sample expected it to be. Make sure you have all the files of the project. Another possibility is that your virtual machine causes a problem with paths or with the Visual Studio project properties.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem.

The solution is to copy the "Shaders" folder from:

`'C:\...\d3d12book-master\Chapter 6 Drawing`

in `Direct3D\Box'`

to

```
'C:\...\d3d12book-master\MyCode\Box\Box'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got this same problem. I worked around it by opening the existing Box.sln VS solution instead of creating my own like the book instructs. I found it in the Box folder right alongside the Shaders folder. This one builds and runs just fine.

I opened an issue in the GitHub repo but it's been a while since there was activity there, so I doubt it'll get addressed.

Answer (score 0):

It was hard to understand what to do to fix this problem. You simply have to make sure the .exe from the build is in the same place as the shader folder and it should work just fine. At least it did for  me. What I did to run this example was simply copy the .exe from the build to the box folder which has the shader folder and the program ran just fine.

Comment: the question is 1y old. there are 2 answers with the same content then yours from februar ad july. What merit has your "answer" that the other 2 have not?`

Answer (score 0):

I learn Dx12 with the same book and code sample. I guess that what actually caused this problem is the function callings in `BoxApp.cpp` at line 354 or 355:

```
    mvsByteCode = d3dUtil::CompileShader(L"Shaders\\color.hlsl", nullptr, "VS", "vs_5_0");
    mpsByteCode = d3dUtil::CompileShader(L"Shaders\\color.hlsl", nullptr, "PS", "ps_5_0");
```

Because `d3dUtil::CompileShader` is defined in `d3dUtil.cpp` at line 90-113, so the callings will be resolved to `d3dUtil.cpp`, and this is where the exception being thrown.

Look the first argument passed to `CompileShader`, it indicates that the shader source code can be found in a folder called "Shaders" in the current directory of your program. So copying "Shaders" into the directory meets the semantics here.

Generally, when your program reads a file, you should use file path to tell your program where the file resides. And you can use either absolute path or relative path. The code here uses relative path.